# Adding missing time values

Tags: r

I have a table that is gives me the date-time that I have received data and the count of how much data was received in a thirty minute interval. My problem is some half hour blocks are missing, and I want to insert them into the column and then insert a 0 in the count column.

Here is an example of what the table looks like:

```
Date-Time           Count
2017-07-13 17:30:00 111

2017-07-13 18:00:00 85

2017-07-13 20:00:00 127

2017-07-13 20:30:00 515
```

I want it to have 18:30:00 0 and so on

Not sure how to do this if anyone has an idea that would be great.

Here is what I have tried to do:

```
starttime <- df[1,`Date-Time`]

for (i in df){
  time <- starttime + 30
  new_dt$datetime <- ifelse(df[i] = time, df$datetime, time)
  new_dt$count <- ifelse(df[i] = time, df$count, 0)
}
```

Comment: Show your best attempt - add some code.

Answer (score 2):

First let's create some dummy data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

time_series <- tibble(
  DateTime = c(
    "2017-07-13 17:30:00",
    "2017-07-13 18:00:00",
    "2017-07-13 20:00:00",
    "2017-07-13 20:30:00"
  ),
  Count = c(111, 85, 127, 515)
) %>%
  mutate(DateTime = ymd_hms(DateTime))
```

Now let's figure out the smallest and largest datetimes that we have in the data.

```
from <- min(time_series$DateTime)
to <- max(time_series$DateTime)
```

Finally, let's create a sequence of dates from `from` to `to` at 30 minute intervals. We then join the existing data to that sequence and replace any missing values of `Count` with zero.

```
tibble(DateTime = seq(from = from, to = to, by = 1800)) %>%
  left_join(time_series) %>%
  mutate(Count = ifelse(is.na(Count), 0, Count))
```

Comment: Nice, beat me to the punch. +1

Comment: Thanks @Val! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I've changed the name of your column `Date-Time` to `Date.Time`.

```
#dput(dat)
dat <-
structure(list(Date.Time = structure(c(1499963400, 1499965200, 
1499972400, 1499974200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    Count = c(111L, 85L, 127L, 515L)), .Names = c("Date.Time", 
"Count"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now, the trick is to use `seq.POSIXct` to create a df with just one column, then `merge` the two dfs.

```
tmp <- data.frame(
    Date.Time = seq(min(dat$Date.Time), max(dat$Date.Time), by = "30 min"))
tmp
            Date.Time
1 2017-07-13 17:30:00
2 2017-07-13 18:00:00
3 2017-07-13 18:30:00
4 2017-07-13 19:00:00
5 2017-07-13 19:30:00
6 2017-07-13 20:00:00
7 2017-07-13 20:30:00

merge(dat, tmp, all.y = TRUE)
            Date.Time Count
1 2017-07-13 17:30:00   111
2 2017-07-13 18:00:00    85
3 2017-07-13 18:30:00    NA
4 2017-07-13 19:00:00    NA
5 2017-07-13 19:30:00    NA
6 2017-07-13 20:00:00   127
```

You can then `rm(tmp)` if you want.

Comment: Ended up using this way as i was more familiar with this. Thank you it worked well for me

Answer (score 2):

While these work, I think the best bet is to use the `padr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(padr)

pad_df <- df %>% 
  pad(interval = '30 mins')
```

If you prefer `0`'s to `NA`'s, then simply:

```
pad_df[is.na(pad_df)] <- 0
```

The `padr` package also has the `thicken` function in case you need to quickly and seamlessly change to a lower frequency.

[padr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/padr/vignettes/padr.html)